# When should I call CoUninitialize?

Tags: c, com, mta

I implemented a function in a DLL encapsulates the asynchronous call to a Out-OF-Proc COM server. It looks like this:

```
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    bool bCoInitialized = false;
    IXXXXInterface* pServer = NULL;
    ISynchronize* pISynchronize = NULL;
    AsyncIXXXXInterface* pAsyncServer = NULL;
    ICancelMethodCalls* pICancel = NULL;

    hr = CoInitializeEx(NULL,COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    if (hr == S_OK || hr == S_FALSE) {
        bCoInitialized = true;
    }
    else if(hr == RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE) {
        bCoInitialized = false;
    }
    else{
        bCoInitialized = false;
        goto cleanup
    }
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_XXXXInterface, NULL,
        CLSCTX_ALL|CLSCTX_ACTIVATE_64_BIT_SERVER, IID_IXXXXInterface, (void**)&pServer);
    if (FAILED (hr)) {
        goto cleanup
    }

    ICallFactory* pCallFactory;
    hr = pServer->QueryInterface (IID_ICallFactory, (void**) &pCallFactory);
    if (FAILED (hr)) {
        goto cleanup
    }

    hr = pCallFactory->CreateCall (IID_AsyncIXXXXInterface, NULL, IID_AsyncIXXXXInterface,
        (IUnknown**) &pAsyncServer);
    pCallFactory->Release();
    if (FAILED (hr)) {
        goto cleanup
    }

    hr = pAsyncServer->QueryInterface(IID_ISynchronize,  (void**) &pISynchronize);
    if (FAILED (hr)) {
        goto cleanup
    }

    hr = pAsyncServer->QueryInterface(IID_ICancelMethodCalls, (void**) &pICancel);
    if (FAILED (hr)) {
        goto cleanup
    }

    // Do something use the async interface.
cleanup:    
    if(pICancel)
        pICancel->Release();
    if(pISynchronize)
        pISynchronize->Release();
    if(pAsyncServer)
        pAsyncServer->Release();
    if(pServer)
        pServer->Release();
    if(bCoInitialized)     // If I comment out these 
        CoUninitialize();  // 2 lines, it will be OK.
```

The problem is when I call the the function in multi-thread, sometimes it will throw exception in combase.dll with call stack in the work thread of COM.
If I just comment out the last 2 lines, it will be OK. It looks like CoUnitialize() will free all the resources while the work thread in the COM thread pool is still using them in some circumstance. I'm not sure whether my though is correct, or there is something wrong elsewhere. If I'm right, how can I avoid this issue by using which API to wait for the work thread release all the resources?

Comment: You'll need to treat a failure of CoInitializeEx() as a fatal problem, it should terminate your program.  Something is seriously wrong when you get RPC_E_CHANGED_MODE, it is a bug in your code, continuing as if nothing happened is not going to turn out well.

Comment: You've not specified whether the crash is in an RPC thread in *this* process or the out-of-proc COM server process. Either way it sounds like you're not marshaling correctly to the other apartment, most likely on a callback interface you setup that never gets properly undone. Since this is out-of-proc, your apartment model makes no real difference. You *must* marshall properly to the apartment in the other process. That aside, taking any COM action **at all** if you've `FAILED(hr)` on `CoInitializeEx()` is a bad move no matter what.